# how show mylist in activity to fragment android

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, fragment

I wish I got the information from a site within a fragment showing my list
See the following code :
.........................................................

As you can see in the activity of the work I've done is I want it in my mouth homefragment displayed, please guide me

Comment: So..you want the content of your activity to be displayed on a [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)? Have you read the article I'm pointing to? Have you tried anything else? Show us your research.

Comment: Please only include the code required to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: //So..you want the content of your activity to be displayed on a Fragment? yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tabs in your activity( Home and New) right? And you want to display the content in Home fragment?  If that is what you meant,

1. Execute the AsyncTask in HomeFragment class. And execute the AsyncTask in **OnCreateView()** method or **OnViewCreated()** method. I dont see execute statement in the code you pasted.

2.There is no need to change anything in AsyncTask part but if you have used "this" for context , use **getActivity()** in its place.

3.Keep Navigation drawer part's code and Toolbar items code in the activity itself.(Eg.onOptionsItemSelected(),onCreateOptionsMenu() etc)

4.Don't forget to move Adapter class to HomeFragment.

I think this helps.

I have edited your code, see if this works.
      public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private ListView lv;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv);
    new mytask().execute("http://musiqikurdi.com/api/get_recent_posts/");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

    return rootView;
}

public class mytask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<MusicModel>> {

    @Override
    protected List<MusicModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentobject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
            JSONArray parentarray = parentobject.getJSONArray("posts");
            StringBuffer finalbufferData = new StringBuffer();


            List<MusicModel> musicModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=0; i < parentarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalobject = parentarray.getJSONObject(i);
                MusicModel musicModel = new MusicModel();
                musicModel.setId(finalobject.getString("id"));
                musicModel.setTitle(finalobject.getString("title").replaceAll("[\\&#8211;]", ""));
                musicModel.setUrl(finalobject.getString("url").replaceAll("[\\&#8211;]", ""));
                musicModel.setDate(finalobject.getString("date").replaceAll("[\\&#8211;]", ""));

                List<MusicModel.category> cateList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int j = 0; j < finalobject.getJSONArray("categories").length(); j++ )
                {
                    MusicModel.category cate = new MusicModel.category();
                    cate.setCateTitle(finalobject.getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
                    cateList.add(cate);
                }
                musicModel.setListCategory(cateList);
                musicModelList.add(musicModel);
            }

            return musicModelList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MusicModel> s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        MusicAdapter adapter = new MusicAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row,s);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
public class MusicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List<MusicModel> musicModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MusicAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MusicModel> objects) {
        super(getActivity(), resource, objects);
        musicModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
        }
        ImageView img;
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;

        img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txt1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txt3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt3);

        txt1.setText(musicModelList.get(position).getId());
        txt2.setText(musicModelList.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}